# How to create an index column, a 2 window moving average column and a 2 window difference column with groupby in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

I have a spark dataframe that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.DataFrame({'country':['a','a','a','a','b','b'], 'value':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'id':[3,5,4,6, 8,7]})
```

I would like to add 3 new columns in this dataframe.

- An index that starts from 1 and increases for each row, by `country`
- A 2 window difference of the `value` column by `country`, ordered by `id`
- A 2 window moving average of the `value` column by country, ordered by `id`

Any ideas how I can do that in one go ?

**EDIT**

The `difference` column should be `[1,2,-1,2,6,-1]` and it is calculated as follows:

- The rows are ordered by `id`. Then, the first rows for each country remain unchanged. Then for the second row for country `a` it is `3-1=2`, for the 3rd row it is `2-3=-1` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the rowsBetween window spec with windows function

```
##%%
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
# Test data
dfs = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('a',1,3),('a',2,5),('a',3,4),('a',4,6),('b',5,8),('b',6,7)],schema=['country','value','id'])
# First window to calculate the id and difference in values
w=Window.partitionBy('country').orderBy('id')
# use row_number() and lag() functions to get the values
df_id = (dfs.withColumn("id",F.row_number().over(w))).withColumn("delta",F.col('value')-F.lag('value',default=0).over(w))
#% Second window to calculate the moving average, sum and difference
w1 = w=Window.partitionBy('country').orderBy('id').rowsBetween(-1,0)
# do the calculations with a window spec of 2, defined by (-1,0) in w1
df = (df_id.withColumn("movingaverage",F.mean('value').over(w1))).withColumn("moving_sum",F.sum('value').over(w1))
# Additional calculation, not requested by the author
df_res = df.withColumn("moving_difference", F.col('value')-F.col("moving_sum"))
```

The results

```
df_res.show()
    +-------+-----+---+-----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|country|value| id|delta|movingaverage|moving_sum|moving_difference|
+-------+-----+---+-----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
|      a|    1|  1|    1|          1.0|         1|                0|
|      a|    3|  2|    2|          2.0|         4|               -1|
|      a|    2|  3|   -1|          2.5|         5|               -3|
|      a|    4|  4|    2|          3.0|         6|               -2|
|      b|    6|  1|    6|          6.0|         6|                0|
|      b|    5|  2|   -1|          5.5|        11|               -6|
+-------+-----+---+-----+-------------+----------+-----------------+
```

Comment: @Radhu. Thank you. Please see edit regarding the `difference` column

Comment: @quant - have updated the code to introduce the column "delta". check it out. 
Note : have left the moving difference, just in case :-)

Comment: Thank you. Another (quick) question. in the rowsBetween, if you input as arguments (-2,0) then it calculates the 3 window etc ? And how does the default value in `F.lag` work together wi the rowsBetween ?

Comment: You're welcome ! 
About the rows between, you are right. you can also change the second value to look forward , like (-3,1).  F.lag() cannot be used with rows between, hence i used it in the first window w. If you need to lag or lead more than one column then you can give it as a parameter like F.lag(col,2,default=0). In this case, the lagged columns will shift two places down, with the default value 0 as the first value in the group. That's where the default values plays the role. If you don't specify it , it takes as Null as the first value in the group.